# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined jest enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Below is my component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { postJobAction } from './redux/postJobActions';

const PostJobComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onPostJobSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const title = event.target.title.value;
    const location = event.target.location.value; // Here is the error.

    dispatch(postJobAction({
      title,
      location,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className='post-job'>
      <form onSubmit={onPostJobSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Job Title</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='title'
            defaultValue=''
            className='job__title'
            placeholder='e.g. Frontend Developer, Project Manager etc.'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Job Location</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='location'
            defaultValue=''
            className='job__location'
            placeholder='e.g. Berlin, Germany.'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostJobComponent;
```

Here is the test case.

```
it('should submit job post form on save button click', () => {
        const onPostJobSubmit = jest.fn();
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');
        expect(onPostJobSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

When I run test I get below error.

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

      22 |     const title = event.target.title.value;
    > 23 |     const location = event.target.location.value;
```

What am I missing and how to fix it?

Comment: @DrewReese I am using  React `17.0.2`.

Comment: @DrewReese it is undefined.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for checking. I really don't see an overt issue with the form component. Is it only in the test that it throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [`.simulate` documentation](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html)

> As noted in the function signature above passing a mock event is optional. Keep in mind that if the code you are testing uses the event for something like, calling event.preventDefault() or accessing any of its properties **you must provide a mock event object** with the properties your code requires.

try adding a mock event object like this:

```
it('should submit job post form on save button click', () => {
    const onPostJobSubmit = jest.fn();
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit', {
      target: {
        title: {
          value: 'some value',
        },
        location: {
          value: 'some value'
        }
      }
    });
    expect(onPostJobSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I made these changes but now I am getting another error. I updated the question with the new error. Could you please take a look and help out?

Comment: @Om3ga you're defining function within the scope of the test and the component doesn't receive a reference to it, so you shouldn't be expecting for it to have been called, even if it has the same name with the one from the component's scope.

Comment: @Om3ga you should rather check how to test the mocked store or if dispatch have been called with the expected data

Comment: no dispatch is not called with all the data.

Comment: The test should be testing whether it has been called with whatever the component is supposed to be calling it with

Comment: When I run the code it works perfectly fine but when I run test it returns this error.